# Clipped layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, clipped

Can you help me design Android layout as the mockup:
[image]

Description:

- Orange layout with rounded radius.
- Green layout is cut off at bottom and overflow at top
- Yellow layout in front of Green and cut off at rounded corner of Orange.

Please help me, I was crazy with this problem.

Thank you so much!

My Code here:

Clipped view

```
public class ClippedView extends FrameLayout {
public ClippedView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ClippedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ClippedView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path clipPath = new Path();
    clipPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(canvas.getClipBounds()), 120, 120, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

It's cut OK but Orange layout cut all side. I want cut children only at bottom

Comment: You might get a better response if you share what you've already tried.

Comment: hi Emragins, I have already edit my topic, please review for me! Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with android, but I'm guessing that using a rectangular clipping as you're trying is going to be impossible.  Is there an arc clipping shape?  You might have to break it into pieces: bottom/top, where the bottom clips everything, but the top arc clips only orange.